# Jquery easyTicker not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using easyTicker Plugin to scroll content on the page and use collapser plugin to truncate words in the ticker. both plugins works smoothly but when i expand the truncated words easyTicker stop working even without throwing any exception. here is the JSFiddler code for my work with above bug.

thanks

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$('.review-wrapper').easyTicker({
    direction: 'up',
    easing: 'swing',
    speed: 'slow',
    interval: 2000,
    visible: 2,
    height: 'auto',
});

$('.circle').collapser({
    mode: 'words',
    truncate: 20,
    effect: 'fade',
    showText: 'Show',
    hideText: 'Hide',
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gayancc/q7qYN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick :) its a little bit raw code :

```
 $('.circle').collapser({
        beforeShow: function() {
            var element = $('.review-wrapper').data('easyTicker');           
            element.stop();
        },
        afterShow: function() {
            var element = $('.review-wrapper').data('easyTicker');
            element.start();
            $('.review-wrapper').mouseenter(); // NEW LINE if is set mousePause in easyTicker
        },
        beforeHide: function() {
            var element = $('.review-wrapper').data('easyTicker');
            element.stop();
        },
        afterHide: function() {
            var element = $('.review-wrapper').data('easyTicker');
            element.start();
        },
        mode: 'words',
        truncate: 20,
        effect: 'fade',
        showText: 'Show',
        hideText: 'Hide'
});
```

Idea is to stop and start scrolling when you are doing toggle transformation (show/hide).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8UCHu/4/)

Comment: hi loncar,that's a good trick but the problem is when start easyTicker mouse stop again not working!!

Comment: I am not sure that I understand that. Why you want to start again easyTicker? I my `jsfiddle` example it is working ok

Comment: Can you update your jsfiddle example with that case?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, when i hovered mouse on scrolled content it's stop [mousePause:1] but on that solution i can't get it done. thanks
here is the updated Jsfiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/gayancc/8UCHu/1/

Comment: Add this line of code : `$('.review-wrapper').mouseenter();` I have updated my example and jsFiddle :)